# LINQ Query Null Error

Tags: vb.net, linq, search

I have am making an email contact search, where I am supposed to open a  text file using the OpenFileDialog, and then  split it to an array and search using LINQ.  I have the openFileDialog working, but when I run my LINQ query, I get the `object reference not set to an instance of an object` error.  Option Infer is on, and as far as I can tell this is set up exactly like some of the examples in my textbook.  Can anyone point me in the right direction??? (textFile is defined as a class variable above the first button code: "`Dim textFile(2) As String`".

Code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnOpen.Click
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    textFile(2) = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    lstOutput.DataSource = IO.File.ReadAllLines(textFile(2))
    lstOutput.SelectedItem = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub btnNameSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNameSearch.Click
    Dim queryName = From line In textFile
                    Let data = line.Split(","c)
                    Let firstName = data(0)
                    Let lastName = data(1)
                    Let email = data(2)
                    Where firstName = txtName.Text
                    Select firstName, lastName, email
    lstName.DataSource = queryName.ToList
End Sub
```

Edit: Code breaks on line 21 "Let data=line.Split(","c)

Comment: Generally you should have something like `If (OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)`, otherwise clicking Cancel would cause the code to execute.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what do you mean by stack trace of the error?

Comment: Also are you sure you don't have extra whitespace in your file? Like the comma you're splitting on doesn't have a space before or after it?  Could you do `where firstName.Trim() == txtName.Text` or something?

Comment: No extra whitespace - firstName,lastName,email address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the filename as the string that LINQ is querying against.  You need to use the file contents itself.

Change your code to something like this:

```
Private lines() As String

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnOpen.Click
    If OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        textFile(2) = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
        lines = IO.File.ReadAllLines(textFile(2))
        lstOutput.DataSource = lines
        lstOutput.SelectedItem = Nothing
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnNameSearch_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnNameSearch.Click
    Dim queryName = From line In lines
                    Let data = line.Split(","c)
                    Let firstName = data(0)
                    Let lastName = data(1)
                    Let email = data(2)
                    Where firstName = txtName.Text
                    Select firstName, lastName, email
    lstName.DataSource = queryName.ToList
End Sub
```

Comment: Fantastic!  Thank you so much!  I've been fighting with this for hours.

Comment: It happens to the best of us.  Staring at the same code for a long time can really cause simple mistakes to be easily overlooked.